# Unable to set width and height on canvas in chart js

Tags: chart.js

I am unable to set width and height on the canvas, it is taking full height and width available on the body.

Could you please help here?
I need to scroll down to see the chart.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <style>
   
 </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  </body>
  <script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  data = {
    datasets: [{
        data: [10, 20, 30,50],
  backgroundColor: ['#ff6384','#36a2eb','#cc65fe', '#ffce56'],
  borderWidth: ['1','1','1', '1'] 
    }],

    labels: ['Red','Yellow','Blue','Green']
 
};
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: data,
 options: {
    legend: {
        display: false,
   responsive: false
      }
    
    }
});
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to put it in a container div element and set the width and height on the container like it is mentioned in the [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html#important-note).

```
<div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:40vh; width:80vw">
    <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```